# Search col, copy serial number and paste into repeating cols vba

Tags: vba, excel

Was hoping someone could help me with a little piece of vba code?
My raw data looks like this:

```
1   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
2   1   311000063552511.00  9/07/2013                                           
3   2   13552500    135525                                          
4   3   871 535316-613  30/03/2015  12:39:20    0   CRD PURCHASE    22900   0   22900       EFTPOS  
5   3   872 407220-029  30/03/2015  15:28:39    0   CRD PURCHASE    22900   0   22900       EFTPOS  
6   3   873 456472-840  30/03/2015  16:41:04    0   CRD PURCHASE    22900   0   22900       EFTPOS  
7   2   13553400    135534                                          
8   3   2077    494053-070  30/03/2015  8:56:31 0   CRD PURCHASE    37763   0   37763       EFTPOS  
9   3   2078    456443-621  30/03/2015  9:55:40 0   CRD PURCHASE    17647   0   17647       EFTPOS  
10  3   2079    455701-331  30/03/2015  11:35:44    1   CHQ PURCHASE    40546   0   0       EFTPOS  
11  3   2080    455701-331  30/03/2015  11:36:27    55  CRD PURCHASE    40546   0   0       EFTPOS  
12  3   2086    552350-690  30/03/2015  14:21:51    0   CRD PURCHASE    22166   0   22166       EFTPOS  
13  3   2087    455702-239  30/03/2015  15:24:34    0   CHQ PURCHASE    23647   0   23647       EFTPOS  
14  3   2088    455701-685  30/03/2015  16:21:31    0   CRD PURCHASE    22166   0   22166       EFTPOS  
15  2   13555200    135552                                          
16  3   1544    516361-514  30/03/2015  11:55:06    0   CHQ PURCHASE    22900   0   22900       EFTPOS  
17  3   1545    407220-745  30/03/2015  14:00:36    0   CRD PURCHASE    24153   0   24153       EFTPOS
```

What I hope to do is: Col A determines what I want to do. So a "2" in Col A means I want to copy the number in Col B1, B5 etc. And replace all the "3's" in Col A with this number.

I want the sheet to look like this once finished:

```
1   1   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
2   1   311000063546919 28/03/2015                                              
3   13552500    871 535316-613  30/03/15    0.527314815 0   CRD PURCHASE    22900   0   22900       EFTPOS      
4   13552500    872 407220-029  30/03/15    0.644895833 0   CRD PURCHASE    22900   0   22900       EFTPOS      
5   13552500    873 456472-840  30/03/15    0.695185185 0   CRD PURCHASE    22900   0   22900       EFTPOS      
6   13553400    2077    494053-070  30/03/15    0.372581019 0   CRD PURCHASE    37763   0   37763       EFTPOS      
7   13553400    2078    456443-621  30/03/15    0.413657407 0   CRD PURCHASE    17647   0   17647       EFTPOS      
8   13553400    2079    455701-331  30/03/15    0.483148148 1   CHQ PURCHASE    40546   0   0       EFTPOS      
9   13553400    2080    455701-331  30/03/15    0.483645833 55  CRD PURCHASE    40546   0   0       EFTPOS      
10  13553400    2086    552350-690  30/03/15    0.598506944 0   CRD PURCHASE    22166   0   22166       EFTPOS      
11  13553400    2087    455702-239  30/03/15    15:24:34    0   CHQ PURCHASE    23647   0   23647       EFTPOS      
12  13553400    2088    455701-685  30/03/15    16:21:31    0   CRD PURCHASE    22166   0   22166       EFTPOS      
13  13555200    1544    516361-514  30/03/15    11:55:06    0   CHQ PURCHASE    22900   0   22900       EFTPOS      
14  13555200    1545    407220-745  30/03/15    14:00:36    0   CRD PURCHASE    24153   0   24153       EFTPOS      
15  13555300    2730    450949-935  30/03/15    0.369259259 0   CRD PURCHASE    22900   0   22900       EFTPOS      
16  13555300    2731    456463-730  30/03/15    0.553101852 0   CRD PURCHASE    34966   0   34966       EFTPOS      
17  13555300    2732    552033-957  30/03/15    0.628530093 0   CRD PURCHASE    27147   0   27147       EFTPOS
```

Hope this doesn't prove too difficult for the great minds on here!
Code I'm currently using isn't right!

```
Dim CellValue As String
Dim RowCrnt As Integer
Dim RowMax As Integer

With Sheets("Sheet2")   ' Replace Sheet1 by the name of your sheet
RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For RowCrnt = 1 To RowMax
CellValue = .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value
If Left(CellValue, 2) = "1355" And CellValue = "3" Then
  .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value = CellValue

End If
Next
End With
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks! :)

Comment: thanks for the edit "jherran"! Sorry for initial ugliness of post! :)

Comment: This condition will never happen `Left(CellValue, 2) = "1355`, because `Len(Left(CellValue, 2))` is always 2

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood what you wanted to do correctly,

This code replaces every `3` in `A` with the first value of `B` where `A=2`

```
Dim CellValue As String
Dim RowCrnt As Integer
Dim RowMax As Integer

With Sheets("Sheet2")   ' Replace Sheet1 by the name of your sheet
RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For RowCrnt = 1 To RowMax
If .Cells(RowCrnt,1) = "2" Then
    .Range("A:A").Replace What:="3", Replacement:=.Cells(RowCrnt,2), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End If
Next
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Uri, 
I'm getting a Compile error, Invalid or unqualified reference on ".Cells(Row, ) ? 
Should I define "Cells"?

Also, looks like you pretty much understood my question, I should have been clearer; So yes, every where there is a "2" The number in Cell B will need to be copied to all the 3's below (As in example above) until the next "2" etc etc.

Comment: of-course you are, it's a snippet out of your code. you'll need to use the surrounding `With`  statement

Comment: I've run this and Am getting the following in Col A:
2
11111111111111100000000000000
11111111111111100000000000000
11111111111111100000000000000
2
11111111111111100000000000000
11111111111111100000000000000
11111111111111100000000000000
11111111111111100000000000000
11111111111111100000000000000
11111111111111100000000000000
11111111111111100000000000000
2
11111111111111100000000000000
11111111111111100000000000000

Comment: Not working I'm afraid :(
So I've tried to run this, but instead of replacing the 3's with the previous value in ColB where there was a "2" in ColA, its just replacing All 3's with a scientific formatted number? (1.11E+28)....Can anyone help with this?

Format should read as above example where number is 13553400, 13555300 etc etc.

Thanks